# Assigning values to undeclared properties

Tags: php, class

I don't understand a concept of class in [php](/questions/tagged/php). I could be wrong.

I looked at a WordPress plugin. The class was defined and the properties of class wasn't created only functions were created.

Consider this example

```
class a
{
    public function show(){
        echo "hello";   
        $this->something = "xyz" ;
        // What is this? How can "something" can be used here;
        // as it is not defined in the class?   
    }
}
```

Then an object of that class was created in another file.

```
$obj = new a();
$obj->anothersomething = "abc"; // is it possible?
```

Enlighten me please.

My question is: Can we assign a value to undeclared property of a class?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through **OOP** basics. And also PHP including files.

Comment: Include that file name in the new file.

Comment: I know how to include files and i well known opp concepts. My question is that how the values are assigning to undeclared properties. @sougata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default class visibility is `public`.
However, it is good practice to explicitly declare class method with it's visibility.

```
class Foo
{
    public function a() {}
    protected function b() {}
    private function c() {}
}
```

As @SougataBose mentioned, I'd suggest you running through [PHP OOP course](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Edit:

When it comes to properties - yes. It is possible to create them dynamically. Again, as a good practice, it is recommended to declare all properties in class body.

Comment: please forgive me. and please stick to the question. i don't need unnecessary details

Answer (score -1):

In this case it's not a function, but a public class method. Normally you need to define it with public/protected/private keyword, but when skipped, it's just public by default. So then in another file you create an instance of this class and call the public method `show()` which can then use class instance properties direct. Or you can assign these properties from outside using  `$obj->anothersomething = "xxx"`, which is not a good practice. All the assignments should be done through setter methods like this  `$obj->setProperty($value);`

Comment: My question is that "something" isn't declared. still a object is assigning it value. that's my question